# Pass a parameter for another select option

Tags: html, mysql, angularjs, servlets, ionic-framework

I want {{fetch.university_id}} for query in another select option!! so that i get my college list under university from MySQL database. but i cant get appropriate wayI i want fetch.university_id as a parameter for docol() method

```
<div class="input-label" ng-init="doUni()">

  University

</div>

<select ng-model="fetchData.university" >

  <option name="{{fetch.university_id}}" ng-repeat="fetch in list" >{{fetch.university_name}}</option>

</select>
```

```
<div class="input-label" ng-init="doCol()">

  College

</div>

<select ng-model="fetchData.college" >

<option name="{{fetch.college_id}}" ng-repeat="fetch in collist" >{{fetch.college_name}}</option>

</select>
```

Comment: option should have value attribute with value like `value="{{fetch.university_id}}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-label" ng-init="doUni()">

  University

</div>

<select ng-model="fetchData.university" data-ng-change="controllerFunction (fetchData.university )">

  <option name="{{fetch.university_id}}" ng-repeat="fetch in list" >{{fetch.university_name}}</option>

</select>

In your controller :

scope.controllerFunction = function  (obj) {

Paas this to your server to fetch colleges -->  obj.university_id

Initialise the response data to -->  collist
```